# Birt with Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, birt

Hai I would like to use Birt with Struts 2. But I am getting the following error.

> HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name frameset.

What could be the cause for this? Where this frameset comes from?

`<birt:viewer id="birt_id" format="pdf" reportDesign="new_report.rptdesign" width="1024" 
    height="500" showParameterPage="false">`

```
  <birt:param name="uid" value="100" ></birt:param>
</birt:viewer>
```

This is my .jsp page. When i try to load this page as the result of some action i am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

S2 is attempting to process a URL created by the Birt tag.

Use the `struts.action.excludePattern` constant to tell S2 not to process any of the URLs used by Birt; the Birt docs and your config determine those.

See the [S2 web.xml config docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/webxml.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

There Maybe You defined a class `[birtFilter]`, web.xml: you can change the position:

```
<filter>
         <filter-name>BirtFilter</filter-name>
         <filter-class>avatar.base.birt.BirtFilter</filter-class>   </filter>   <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>BirtFilter</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   </filter-mapping>
```

before `sturts2`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```